# Jenkins parametrized build, adding new form inputs dynamically

Tags: dynamic, plugins, jenkins, parameters, user-input

I have a Jenkins job with parametrized build. I was wondering if there is any way to make those parameters dynamic in a way that user can add/delete parameters when she hits "Build with parameters"? Something like jQuery dynamic input (I found an example here http://www.aorank.com/tutorial/createformdynamically/dynamicallyformcreation.html)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWCiT.png)

I do really care about input text forms only. I looked up different plugins like "Active Choice Parameters", "Dynamic Parameter" and others. They all work with predefined values using Groovy scripts, but my goal is have the user to add as many text fields as she wants, put the data somewhere, ideally assign to Environment variable so I can use it in my pre-build, post-build scripts.

Comment: Better late than never... Have you tried the pipeline plugin? I read a groovy file in the branch and generate input fields accordingly. I guess you can also do that using a groovy step in a free-style job, but then you would have to have administrative credentials and a better understanding of the Jenkins model.